# Minimal polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $K_{\phi_i}$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ with characteristic polynomial $$f(t)=(-1)(\phi_1(t))^{n_1}\dots(\phi_k(t))^{n_k}$$, where $\phi_i(t)$'s are distinct irreducible monic polynomials.

Define $K_{\phi_i}=\{x\in V:(\phi_i(T))^{p}(x)=0 \text{ for some p}\in\Bbb N \}$

Is the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $K_{\phi_i}$ $=(\phi_i(t))^{n_i}$ ?

I know that $K_{\phi_i}=N((\phi_i(T))^{n_i})$, so the minimal polynomial of $T$ to $K_{\phi_i}$ divides $(\phi_i(t))^{n_i}$, then I stuck.

Comment: You meant $\phi_i(T)^p(x)=0$. For the minimal polynomial of $T_i$ the restriction of $T$ to $K_{\phi_i}$ to make sense you must show that $T_i$ sends $K_{\phi_i}$ to itself. Then (by definition) the minimal polynomial divides any polynomial $g(t)$ such that $g(T_i)=0$ (here $g(t)=\phi_i(t)^p$)

Comment: I know that $K_{\phi_i}$ is T-invariant, but how to prove the minimal polynomial = $\phi_i(t)^{n_i}$

Comment: In general it is not. Depending on $p$ and $T$ it can be any factor of $\phi_i(t)^{\min (n_i,p)}$. Try with $T$ the identity or $T=0$.

Comment: So I can conclude that the minimal polynomial of $T_i$ is of the form $(\phi_i(t))^s$ for some $s$

Comment: From that it divides $\phi_i(t)^{\min (n_i,p)}$ (in $L[t]$ where $L$ is the field such that $T$ is $L$-linear)

Comment: thanks for your help